# AndEngine Error in using Timer

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using a timer within AndEngine, but it's tossing this error at me.

Here's the method from which the error is being thrown:

```
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3f,
            new ITimerCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    SceneManager.getInstance().createMenuScene();
                    mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                }
            }));
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```

I've tracked it to this line here in the Engine class:

```
        } finally {
            this.mEngineLock.unlock();
        }
```

Can anyone help?

```
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at edu.ian.andenginetest.SceneManager.disposeSplashScene(SceneManager.java:50)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at edu.ian.andenginetest.SceneManager.createMenuScene(SceneManager.java:57)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at edu.ian.andenginetest.MainActivity$1.onTimePassed(MainActivity.java:73)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:98)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:597)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:585)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:56)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
02-21 03:39:55.056: E/AndroidRuntime(27796):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

Here's a link to the github commit with my code: https://github.com/mkaziz/EECS-499---Android-Shooter/commit/63dab77fe43f70543b06ea6436249c8401b339bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [code on github](https://github.com/mkaziz/EECS-499---Android-Shooter) (you left on [AndEngine forum](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/thread-locking-error-of-some-variety-in-engine-class-t11063.html), but not here):
In your `MainActivity` class `onCreateScene()` function,
you call `SceneManager`'s `createSplashScene()` which executes AndEngine `onCreateSceneFinished()` callback once.
And, after return back to `OnCreateScene()` in `MainActivity`, you execute same callback again.
If you trace into AndEngine code, you will know this will cause the `onPopulateScene()` in `MainActivity` executes twice too. So, you'll create two timer instances, and get NPE when second timer disposing the splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm scrapping much of my original answer.  I still think what's happening is unregistering a TimerHandler within its own callback is causing the null pointer by taking away its reference to the engine before it's (in some sense) "done".  In other words, TimerHandler appears to do its unlock on the engine *after* calling onTimePassed().

Something else to consider/try:  Is this happening within your main update thread?  If not, consider moving it to the main thread.  E.g.,

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
          // put it here.


}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I believe that here `OnTimePassed()` is essentially the equivalent of `onFinished()`. This particular interface that I am creating an instance of doesn't even have any other methods.

Comment: @khalid13 Let me know if the issue is resolved by moving to the update thread.

Comment: @khalid Looks like has the right answer.  You didn't tell us at SO about the github code!

Comment: My apologies for not posting the github code. I made the stackoverflow post earlier and I didn't think to link to the repo then. I've edited it into the question now, and upvoted your answer. Sorry!

Comment: @khalid13 no worries.  Thank you for the (honorary) upvote! :)